# Preserve spaces used in search string in the resulting string or re.sub function

Tags: python, regex

I am iterating through a dictionary and replacing any keys found in a string with its value. There are two conditions I am searching for, which in standard python string formatting looks like this:   `if (' '+key+'' in x) or (x.startswith(key)): x = x.replace(key, matches[key])`

I would ideally like to use regular expressions for this replacement.

Currently I am using
`re.sub(r'(^|\s)FIRST(\s)', '1st', string)`
which properly implements the conditions for finding the strings to be replaced, but the output consumes the space character in the search pattern.
For Example:

```
strings = ['FIRST BASE', 'TWENTYFIRST ST.', 'CHRISTS FIRST CHURCH', 'TWENTY FIRST']
for string in strings:
    print((re.sub(r'(^|\s)FIRST(\s)', '1st', string)))
```

prints:

```
1stBASE
TWENTYFIRST ST.
CHRISTS1stCHURCH
TWENTY FIRST
```

How can I search for a string surrounded by spaces and replace with a value without losing the spaces?

Comment: `(?<!\S)FIRST(?!\S)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
(^|\s+)FIRST($|\s+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iiCYCj/4)

Or with negative lookbehind and negative lookahead:

```
(?<!\S)FIRST(?!\S)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kCoyya/2/)